# UIViewController inside XIB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xib

Currently I'm struggling with creating a subclass of `UIViewController` or `UINavigationController` with **XIB** file as a view.

When I create everything from the Xcode's menu (New File -> Class -> With Nib... etc.) I get a **XIB** but only with a plain `UIView` but I want `UIViewController` instead.

I read somewhere that **XIBs** are only for a views and you have to handle controller in code, is it true? Because as you can read [here](http://www.valmikam.com/2011/09/add-uinavigatorcontroller-ui-and-load.html) it's possible to insert Navigation Controller component into **XIB**. But I have one problem with the code from this tutorial - I get empty view with empty `UINavigationBar`. When I do the same with regular View Controller I get info abut this controller being used more than once...

I'm not trying to force Interface Builder to do something unusual but I want to know if this is possible (it would be easier and nicer to modify view controller component insted of a content view)? And if it is, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I have just checked to confirm whether it is possible and to my surprise it is! **You can have `UIViewController`s inside Xibs**

The test was done in XCode 10.1, Swift 4.2.

I have never used it before, but i thought since it gives you the option from the item library to pick view controllers, it has to be possible. I have added one to my `xib`, and just like in the storyboards, i have linked it with class, set `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s and it all worked perfectly fine.

**The key thing is to instantiate it like this:**

```
// Method inside the `UIViewController` you want to present our view controller from xib
// The xib file is `XibViewController.xib` and it has only one item inside - `UIViewController` with custom class set to `XibViewController`

guard let xibViewController = UINib(nibName: "XibViewController", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? XibViewController else { return }

present(xibViewController, animated: true)
```

here you can find my test project: https://github.com/stoqn4opm/XibViewController

Answer (score 0):

An XIB file is used for building content that is viewable on a screen. A UIViewController is not viewable. It instead owns a view (which is viewable) created from an XIB or from code.

I think from what you are trying to do is use a storyboard which lets you visually layout your UIViewControllers to define there segue from each other (in your case in a Navigation Controller) which means show the next UIViewControllers view and put it in the UIViewController hierarchy.

Comment: I understand that XIB files are only used for viewable content and I understand the concept which lays behind Storyboards. But I want to use a UIViewController component inside XIB to have eg. `UINavigationBar` for the comfort of designing view in Interface Builder.